Linking light Power to a texture emission
OK so, I am making a Moving Head Light (like you see at events or shows) and I would like to link the light Power to the emission strength of a texture.
Basically, I want to use the Light Power to drive the emission strength.
Is this possible? Because I cant figure it out or find anything about it anywhere!
I'm from a C4D background so, I would use the "User Data" and "XPresso" feature to achieve it there.
Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Sure, a simple way would be to use a driver. Go to the light source and in its properties right-click on the Power value and choose Copy as New Driver.
Then go to the Shader Editor to edit the material with the Emission shader. Right-click on the Strength value and choose Paste Driver. The field will turn purple to indicate there is a driver, now the Strength will get the same value as the Power.
If the Power is too strong for the Emission shader and you want to use only a certain amount of it, you can now right-click on the driver in the Strength value again and choose Edit Driver.
In the opening dialogue box switch the driver's Type to Scripted Expression. In the Expression field should be a variable "energy", which is the value you get from the light source. Simply enter some mathematical operation, for example energy/10 or energy*0.1 to use only 10% of the light's Power.


Thank you so much! I know there would be a way somehow! Thanks again.
